# Symfony 5 on synology DSM 6.2.3-25426 Update 3

Tags: php, symfony, symfony5, synology

I would like to move to Symfony 5 as an development environment. I tried to install using composer on my synology NAS with DSM 6.2.3-25426 Update 3.

PHP 7.3 as php version.

I followed the steps in the symfony getting started guide and everything seemed to install smoothly apart from having to change the php config a little.

However, after installing the symfony demo application I cannot get it to run. I use the network address of the synology in the browser to test as follows: http://192.168.x.x:8000, but the browser just times out. I have apache 2.4 running on the nas, but want to use the 'local' symfony webserver as recommended for development.

Any ideas?

This is one of my first post here, hope I'm following the posting indications correctly.

Starting the local webserver in the folder of the demo app gives following output:

```
*Tailing Web Server log file (/root/.symfony/log/0680ffe11c930b95313342ec04d46c96d69954df.log)
Tailing PHP log file (/root/.symfony/log/0680ffe11c930b95313342ec04d46c96d69954df/7daf403c7589f4927632ed3b6af762a992f09b78.log)
 [OK] Web server listening
      The Web server is using PHP CLI 7.3.16
      https://127.0.0.1:8000
[Web Server ] Mar 16 16:46:14 |DEBUG  | PHP    Reloading PHP versions
[Web Server ] Mar 16 16:46:15 |DEBUG  | PHP    Using PHP version 7.3.16 (from .php-version from current dir: /volume1/web/symfdemo/.php-version)
[Application] Mar 16 15:31:54 |INFO   | PHP    Deprecated: "continue" targeting switch is equivalent to "break". Did you mean to use "continue 2"?
[Application] Mar 16 15:31:54 |INFO   | PHP    User Deprecated: Auto-registration of the command "Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\Command\SendEmailCommand" is deprecated since Symfony 3.4 and won't be supported in 4.0. Use PSR-4 based service discovery instead.
[Application] Mar 16 15:31:54 |INFO   | PHP    User Deprecated: Auto-registration of the command "Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\Command\DebugCommand" is deprecated since Symfony 3.4 and won't be supported in 4.0. Use PSR-4 based service discovery instead.
[Application] Mar 16 15:31:54 |INFO   | PHP    User Deprecated: Auto-registration of the command "Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\Command\NewEmailCommand" is deprecated since Symfony 3.4 and won't be supported in 4.0. Use PSR-4 based service discovery instead.
[Application] Mar 16 15:31:54 |INFO   | PHP    User Deprecated: Auto-registration of the command "Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\Command\GenerateCommandCommand" is deprecated since Symfony 3.4 and won't be supported in 4.0. Use PSR-4 based service discovery instead.
[Application] Mar 16 15:31:54 |INFO   | PHP    User Deprecated: Auto-registration of the command "Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\Command\GenerateDoctrineCrudCommand" is deprecated since Symfony 3.4 and won't be supported in 4.0. Use PSR-4 based service discovery instead.
[Application] Mar 16 15:31:54 |INFO   | PHP    User Deprecated: Auto-registration of the command "Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\Command\GenerateBundleCommand" is deprecated since Symfony 3.4 and won't be supported in 4.0. Use PSR-4 based service discovery instead.
[Application] Mar 16 15:31:54 |INFO   | PHP    User Deprecated: Auto-registration of the command "Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\Command\GenerateDoctrineEntityCommand" is deprecated since Symfony 3.4 and won't be supported in 4.0. Use PSR-4 based service discovery instead.
[Application] Mar 16 15:31:54 |INFO   | PHP    User Deprecated: Auto-registration of the command "Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\Command\GenerateControllerCommand" is deprecated since Symfony 3.4 and won't be supported in 4.0. Use PSR-4 based service discovery instead.
[Application] Mar 16 15:31:54 |INFO   | PHP    User Deprecated: Auto-registration of the command "Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\Command\GenerateDoctrineFormCommand" is deprecated since Symfony 3.4 and won't be supported in 4.0. Use PSR-4 based service discovery instead.
[Web Server ] Mar 16 16:46:15 |INFO   | PHP    listening path="/volume1/@appstore/PHP7.3/usr/local/bin/php" php="7.3.16" port=42752*
```

Comment: Please share more detail - which exact problem are you facing? The log contains a lot of deprecation messages, and to me they don't look related to Symfony 5 after all

Comment: Sorry for being unclear... After installing symfony on the synology nas I installed the symfony demo application and was unable to access it from my client development machine through the browser. Turns out I was so focused on the installation process that I forgot to open the firewall at port 8000... sigh!

Answer (score 0):

This looks like you started the server with `symfony serve` which defaults to https://127.0.0.1:8000 for the page. The output from the console above also shows where it's listening.

I should have also been more clear with the next steps assuming your code will move out of development. You'll want to look at [Symfony Webserver Configurations](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html) carefully and evaluate your best options with Apache (or Nginx).

Comment: Thx! Will get a look at it for my first deployment!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for being unclear... After installing symfony on the synology nas I installed the symfony demo application and was unable to access it from my client development machine through the browser. Turns out I was so focused on the installation process that I forgot to open the firewall at port 8000... sigh!